# providing R script templates with my package and open them easily

Tags: r, package

I have some script I want to provide to the user together with my package.

The normal way is to put them into the `inst` folder.

My problem is now. I want to allow the user to copy the script into the local directory so he can make changes on the default settings and execute the script locally.

Is there a comfortable way to open these provided scripts? Can I create links to the script within the package vignettes? Or has anyone a better solution instead of using a complicated command like this

```
file.copy(system.file('test.R','MyPackage'), '.')
```

Specially in this case, the user has to know the script name.

Thanks for any kind of suggestion.

Comment: Why not include a function in your package that acts as a wrapper for `file.copy(system.file(...))`.  Your function could be `copy_package_template(template, copy_to)`.  Then the help file would explain what character string to pass to `template` to get the desired script file (assuming there are multiple) and `copy_to` is the place the user wants the copy to be written.

Comment: I thought about that, but my costumers love to click a button :-)... Ok, I could provide a shiny wrapper to copy the file, but I thought there might be something like a link to put into the vignette...

Comment: Might be out of my level of expertise.  Perhaps a .bat file? (not sure how that would ship with the package though).

Comment: @Benjamin, is there actually a way to get the package name itself? I know how my package is called, I just thing to make it a bit more foolproof.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking.

Comment: To get the `'MyPackage'` name directly with a function like `self` or so. I mean, I can type my package name by hand but I am pretty sure, when I ever rename my package, I would forget to change it within the script :-)